# Drupal 8.2.3 installation missing module installation

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Hello I have just spun up a localhost WAMP drupal 8.2.3 instance and have come across an issue. It seems as though the install module button is missing from the Extend page. I have already checked permissions and that the update manager is enabled. This did fix the issue for the installation of new themes but not the extending modules

Has anybody come across this yet ?

Thanks

Comment: I have an update that you can force the page by going to /admin/modules/install but this still doesn't explain the missing button on the extend page

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me! Drupal 8 Unable to find install new module option after a latest installation of Drupal 8.* (Not sure if it works for D9**)

step 1 : Check if the Update manager module is enabled, if its not unable then enable it and click Install. Go to admin panel and see if you can view Install new module button If its still not visible then go to step 2.

Step 2 : If you still unable to see button Install new module then open url for e.g. http://yourprojectname.com/update.php or http://localhost/drupalsite/update.php
Use update.php utility to update your database whenever a new release of Drupal or a module is installed. Please read all the instructions before pressing Continue button.
Once Continue button is pressed, it will take some time to perform update operation, On complete it will show a message "No pending updates."

Step 3: Go to admin panel and see if can view Install new module button

https://github.com/SatheMangesh/Drupal8_9/blob/master/qa/Drupal8notes.txt

Answer (score 0):

If the permissions are correct, does clearing the cache work?